# Equation relating damage to fall height

Tags: energy, kinematics, collision, free-fall

I am looking for an equation that relates the falling height of an object to the damage it will receive.  The output answer doesn't need units (because there is no unit for general damage).  It just needs to be a relative model. I initially thought that velocity on impact modeled damage.  Then I thought about acceleration on impact.  Then I considered kinetic energy, and impulse on impact.  I'm not sure if any of these are right.  I am generally looking for an equation to model damage to a *human* jumping from certain heights, ignoring air resistance.

Comment: You may wish to review the 1959 NASA report [Human Tolerance to Rapidly Applied Accelerations: A Summary of the Literature](https://archive.org/details/nasa_techdoc_19980228043).  The basic take-away from this report is that the direction, duration, magnitude, and rate of onset of the acceleration all make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

== disclaimer: I am a physicist working in the tradition of the [spherical cow approximation](https://www.wired.com/2011/02/what-is-up-with-the-spherical-cow/). I am not hampered by any relevant medical knowledge. ==

Braking bones takes energy. For a human falling from a height this energy is provided by the gravitational energy associated with the drop in height for the center of mass. For a human falling inelastically on a hard immovable surface, and ignoring air resistance, virtually all gravitational energy gets dissipated into the body. I am going to assume that the portion of this dissipated energy that goes into bone deformation is independent of height of falling (see however note at the end).

How much bone damage results from a given amount of gravitational energy dissipated is controlled by the [fracture toughness](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_toughness) $K$ of human bones. This fracture toughness is expressed in units $Pa\sqrt{m}$. From dimensional analysis on the three quantities of interest (gravitational energy $mgH$ dissipated into a human of mass $m$ dropping by $H$ meters under influence of a gravitational acceleration $g$, bone toughness $K$, and resulting total area of bone fracture $A$) it follows that the bone damage scales as 
$$A  \approx (mgH/K)^{4/5}$$ 
This means that a 12 meters fall would incur twice as much bone damage than a 5 meters fall.
I would argue that in reality a height dependency steeper than $H^{4/5}$ will likely be observed as for lower heights of falling a larger relative portion of the energy will be dissipated into soft tissue.

Answer (score 0):

There is this experiment of dropping iron spheres in sand. When "damage" is taken as the diameter of the impact "crater", a log-log plot will show a straight line, indicating a power-law relation. The diameter is often proportional to the impact energy to the power 1/4. This can be understood as the volume of the crater times the height over which the sand is lifted.

Comment: So if I jump from 5.1 meters I will sustain x damage.  And if I jump from 81 meters I will sustain 2x damage?  This seems a little odd, if I'm doing the calculation correctly.

Comment: @DanielWilliams No, the hole in the ground will be about $(81/5.1)^{1/4}=2$ twice as big and deep. My point was that damage was a function of energy $mgh$ or of $mv^2/2$ at impact.